# I have an Flutter APK file and I need to automate it using BDD cucumber framework

Tags: javascript, flutter, cucumber, bdd

How to automate flutter APK file(debug mode) using BDD Framework?

I want to automate flutter APK by attaching feature file, stepdefinition file with a flutter APK file which I received in debug mode. I want some help to automate it using BDD. Thanks in advance.